# PHP $GLOBALS variable issue in included file

Tags: php, variables, global

I recently moved a large CubeCart installation to a new server and it created a whole bunch of issues.  Most of them I'm getting sorted out error by error, but I'm stuck on this one:

In the main index.php file the config file is included, which sets key variables like $glob['rootDir'].  Then a few lines later in the main index.php file another important script is included and calls some of those $glob variables, but under the $GLOBALS superglobal.  However this isn't working.  If I put on the second included file var_dump($GLOBALS) it's all there... but if I put echo $GLOBALS['rootDir'] I get nothing.
I'm not getting any bad errors or anything, just Undefined Index.

Is this an issue with PHP settings?  The site was working fine before on the previous server, though I don't know what version of PHP it was running or specific settings.

Code samples:

MAIN INDEX FILE:

```
//INCLUDE CORE VARIABLES & FUNCTIONS
include_once("includes/global.inc.php");
//... other stuff ...
include_once("includes/sessionStart.inc.php");
```

GLOBAL.INC.PHP:

```
$glob['dbhost'] = 'localhost';
//other variables, including $glob['rootRel'];
```

SESSIONSTART.INC.PHP:

```
$sessionDomain = substr($GLOBALS['rootRel'],0, strlen($GLOBALS['rootRel'])-1);
//the above is where it throws Undefined Index
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$glob and $GLOBALS are different variables, so this behaviour is ok.

Comment: I understand that but for some reason I was under the impression that all variables set anywhere in the script are available under the $GLOBALS variable.  I guess that wouldn't make sense though, as it would then be something like $GLOBALS['glob']['rootDir'].  Very strange though that it was working before on the other server.